# Add panorama item in selected index

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I need to add a panorama item in a selected index like remove ,instead of adding in the last by default.Is it possible to do that

Comment: I didnt see any command to do that

Comment: So you've tried nothing?

Comment: I am a beginner in wp7 development and silverlight.I have gone through many materials and you know all the materials cant give full information.We all have to study from any source the books which i have read and the sites which i have refer didn't give the answer that's why i am asking this question. If you want me to try it is really appreciated and kindly give me some links to know about that  this not the exact answer i expected

Comment: My point is that in the time it took to write your question you could have looked at the documentation online (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama(v=vs.92).aspx) and seen what methods the Items collection supports and would have got your answer. To simply say "I want to do X. Is it possible?" shows no effort on your part. If you want people to help you should make it easy for them. Explain what you've tried and why/if that didn't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly feasible.

First give your panorama control an explicit name (for example x:Name="MyPanorama")
Then use code similar to the following to insert a panorama item at a specific index:

```
MyPanorama.Items.Insert(0, new PanoramaItem() {Header = "Panoramo 0"});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this as PanoramaItems can either be set directly or bound through an ItemsSource.

The [Panorama](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) `Items` property is just an [ItemsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection%28v=vs.95%29) and so support `Add()`, `Clear()`, `Insert()` and `Remove()` methods which should cover all the scenarios you mention in your question.

Alternatively, if you specify an [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms593015%28vs.95%29) which is populated with an Enumerable which also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then you could just update the source directly.